# Insert Google places API into Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places

I am new to android studio and I am trying to insert a `google places search bar` in a `fragment` by using the `google places api`. This fragment where the places api has to go is accessed via a `navigation drawer`.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.pickmyride;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.AutocompleteSessionToken;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {

private PlacesClient placesClient;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account,container,false);

   Places.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
    placesClient = Places.createClient(AccountFragment.this);
    final AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

}

}
```

I am getting the following error:

> createclient(android.content.context) in places cannot be applied to 'myactivity.java'

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are having an error at the IDE because you are not passing the context to the function.

In order to get the context in a fragment, you should before get the activity that "holds" the fragment.

You should use:

```
 getActivity()
```

Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

got the info from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment

and once you have the activity, you can getContext.

So, to sum up:

instead of

```
 AccountFragment.this
```

use

```
 getActivity().this
```

let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, getActivity() worked just fine!

Comment: can we add google place API in two places? I mean first I have use in create account and then in Edit fragment... The error I got is on create account activity it is working but in edit fragment it is showing couldn't load result. I have implement google place api in activity and in fragment.. Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving a context. The fragment is attached with an activity, so you must give the context of this activity. You can give application context if you wish too.

Try:

```
getActivity();
```

or:

```
getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, getActivity() worked just fine!

Comment: i'm glad to hear that.